# construction with compass and ruler

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

There are given two parallel lines, a segment of length b,  and a point A.
Construct with compass and ruler a line that passes through A and intercepts the two parallel lines such as the segment of interception of the two parallel lines is of length b.

When A is between the two parallel lines I can construct a circle of diameter b and center A, but when A is not between them I dont know what to do. Please do not use the [Intercept theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intercept_theorem) as it should be solved only with compass and ruler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First construct one line that crosses the parallel lines at a distance of $b$.

Then construct a parallel to it through $A$.

Comment: Do you work for Staples?  That was easy ;-) .  +1